# What does ‘engorgimpressed’ actually mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the script of *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* by J.K. Rowling, John Tiffany, and Jack Thorne, I found this word extremely confusing.

> SCORPIUS: So let me get this right — the plan is Engorgement …
>
> ALBUS: Yes, Scorpius, that soap, if you may …
>
> *Scorpius fishes a soap out of the sink.*
>
> Engorgio.
>
> *He fires a bolt from his wand across the room. The soap blows up to four times its size.*
>
> SCORPIUS: Nice. Consider me engorgimpressed.

Comment: *Engorged* + *impressed*? Seems like an error or a portmanteau.

Comment: no, I don't think it is an error coz this word really exists but I couldn't figure out its meaning

Comment: It's a play on the words *engorged* and *impressed*. It's uttered in the context of discussing an *engorgement* spell, right? It's not a particularly good play on words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a play on words, [*engorgio*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Engorgement_Charm) and *impressed*:

> This kind of play-on-words is echoed in *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, when a character demonstrates the Engorgement spell (Engorgio!) and another character responds, "Consider me engorgimpressed."
>
> - From [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/wl/harry-potter-and-witty-wordplay/)

Comment: It would be more constructive if people have a reason for down-voting. As I understand it, Laurel should have mentioned that it was a portmanteau and a *community wiki* answer might have been better seeing @Silenus' words have been directly used. Perhaps an [edit] could sort this out.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I *did* cite my source. Keep in mind that it does take a little time to compose an answer, and I wasn't going to abandon my work because someone posted a comment in the meantime (keep in mind that answers belong in the answer section).